# Pandas: find matching rows in two dataframes (without using `merge`)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matching, isin

Let's suppose I have these two dataframes with the same number of columns, but possibly different number of rows:

```
tmp = np.arange(0,12).reshape((4,3))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=tmp) 

tmp2 = {'a':[3,100,101], 'b':[4,4,100], 'c':[5,100,3]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=tmp2)

print(df)
   0   1   2
0  0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11

print(df2)
     a    b    c
0    3    4    5
1  100    4  100
2  101  100    3
```

I want to verify if the rows of `df2` are matching any rows of  `df`, that is I want to obtain a series (or an array) of boolean values that gives this result:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

I think something like the `isin` method should work, but I got this result, which results in a dataframe and is wrong:

```
print(df2.isin(df))
       a      b      c
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
```

As a constraint, I wish to not use the `merge` method, since what I am doing is in fact a check on the data before applying merge itself.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html), which will compare all elements in your arrays and return `True` or `False` for each element for each array.

Then using [`all()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/all) on each array, will get your desired output as the function returns `True` if all elements are true:

```
>>> pd.Series([m.all() for m in np.isin(df2.values,df.values)])

0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Breakdown of what is happening:

```
# np.isin
>>> np.isin(df2.values,df.values)

Out[139]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]])

# all()
>>> [m.all() for m in np.isin(df2.values,df.values)]

Out[140]: [True, False, False]

# pd.Series()
>>> pd.Series([m.all() for m in np.isin(df2.values,df.values)])

Out[141]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: This sounds inefficient. It is O(n^2) where n is the number of elements in the data frames. Since OP just wants matching rows, it should be doable in O(n).

Comment: According to the answer below it's not the most inefficient approach, actually much much better than using ```apply```.  I tested the other answers, the ones that work for me are Corralien's and sammy's which are all inefficient apparently. The other ones didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

There may be more efficient solutions, but you could append the two dataframes can call `duplicated`, e.g.:

```
df.append(df2).duplicated().iloc[df.shape[0]:]
```

This assumes that all rows in each DataFrame are distinct. Here are some benchmarks:

```
tmp1 = np.arange(0,12).reshape((4,3))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=tmp1,  columns=["a", "b", "c"]) 

tmp2 = {'a':[3,100,101], 'b':[4,4,100], 'c':[5,100,3]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=tmp2)

df1 = pd.concat([df1] * 10_000).reset_index()
df2 = pd.concat([df2] * 10_000).reset_index()

%timeit df1.append(df2).duplicated().iloc[df1.shape[0]:]
# 100 loops, best of 5: 4.16 ms per loop
%timeit pd.Series([m.all() for m in np.isin(df2.values,df1.values)])
# 10 loops, best of 5: 74.9 ms per loop
%timeit df2.apply(frozenset, axis=1).isin(df1.apply(frozenset, axis=1))
# 1 loop, best of 5: 443 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.in1d`:

```
>>> df2.apply(lambda x: all(np.in1d(x, df)), axis=1)
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Another way, use `frozenset`:

```
>>> df2.apply(frozenset, axis=1).isin(df1.apply(frozenset, axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a MultiIndex (expensive IMO):

```py
pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2).isin(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df))
Out[32]: array([ True, False, False])
```

Another option is to create a dictionary, and run `isin`:

```py
df2.isin({key : array.array for key, (_, array) in zip(df2, df.items())}).all(1)
Out[45]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df[~df.apply(tuple,1).isin(df2.apply(tuple,1))]
```

Here is my result:

[image: Result]